# Reading a string echoed from PHP into java?

Tags: java, php, android, string, json

I am trying to use the following code to retrieve a response from a server echoed through PHP.  The string compare methods compareTo() and (...).equals(..) do not act properly when this code is executed.  I have tried all sorts of options and I'm convinced that in spite of appearing to convert the response to string format, "responseText" does not have the typical string properties.  If I have 3 string literal statements, one of which is echoed from findUser.php.  How can I read it into java in a way that will allow me to determine the contents of the string as i am trying to do here?  I have found a lot of discussion about needing to create BufferedReader object, but I do not understand how to implement that.  If someone would please lay out the steps for me, I would be very appreciative.

```
 try {  
      HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
      HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(".../findUser.php");  
      httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  
      HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);  
      final String responseText =  EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());  


      if(responseText.compareTo("Not Registered") == 0 || responseText.compareTo("Error") == 0) {  
          Log.i("KYLE","TRUE");
          // DISPLAY ERROR MESSAGE  
          TextView loginError = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.loginErrorMsg);  
          loginError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          loginError.setText(responseText); 
      }  
      else {  
          GlobalVars.username = userEmail;  
          Login.this.finish();  
          Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this,Purchase.class);  
          startActivity(intent);
      }  
      catch(Exception e) {Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());}
```

}

Comment: So have you tried logging the value of `responseText`?

Comment: he has that, in the line `loginError.setText(responseText)` - would've been nice if he included the output of course...

Comment: @Spyder - Hm, I don't know. He says the `compareTo()` method doesn't work properly, which I thought meant that the corresponding block of code is never executed. I'd like to see the value logged before the conditionals.

Answer (score 1):

If your `responseText` log message looks correct but the comparison methods are returning false, then you likely have a character set issue. There are many cases of what appears to be the same character appearing at different code points of different character sets.

The documentation for [EntityUtils.toString()](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html#toString%28org.apache.http.HttpEntity%29) states that when no character set is specified, it tries to analyse the entity or just falls back to ISO-8859-1.

UTF-8 is generally a safe default to use. Try adding this to the top of your PHP script:

```
<?php 
   header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8'); 
?>
```

EntityUtils should pick that up, if not you can pass "utf-8" to the toString() method to force it to use the same character set.

Comment: When I log the value of responseText, it appears in LogCat to be the same string, so I think it's definitely a character issue.  I tried adding that statement to the header and no luck.  How do I pass 'utf-8' to toString()?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Check out the docs (right above the `toString(Entity)` method you're using). Just add it as a second argument.

Comment: I still haven't solved this.  I am going to post a new message

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple more ways to read data from a response.

```
InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
```

(Method 1) Read data one line at a time using a buffered reader

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

    String readData = "";
    String line = "";

    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        readData += line;
    }
```

(Method 2) Read data one byte at a time, then convert to string

```
    byte[] buffer = new byte[10000]; //adjust size depending on how much data you are expecting
    int readBytes = inputStream.read(buffer);

    String dataReceived = new String(buffer, 0, readBytes);
```